# WPF Textbox Animation not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, textbox, storyboard

I have a textbox and then an animation but only when the textbox is focused.

however this doesn't seem to work and i'm guessing because the animation is separate to the Control Template? How can i combine the two? Here is what i have so far.

```
    <Window.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">

                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Transparent"/>
                              <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.66" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="51.274"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.66" Value="51.274"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="97.205"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="53.542"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.66" Value="53.542"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="4.625"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard></BeginStoryboard></Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

  <Grid>

    <TextBox Margin="180,142.5,129,153.5" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" SelectionBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle1}">TextBox</TextBox>

    <Path Data="M0.5,0.75 L170,0.5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1.75" Margin="180,163.781,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0.204"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF00E8FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1.125" Margin="278.29,164.083,0,0" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="2.13" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Remove your `x:Key` and try.

Comment: makes no difference.

Comment: You have to remove the style form your `TextBox`. removing `x:Key` means you are applying the style to all `TextBox` type in your case. `TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"` which is the one says this style apples to all textbox. adding  `x:Key` and specifying to `TextBox` is explicitly adding the style to particular `TextBox`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are confused. My problem is my animation (path & rectangle) will not work when the textbox is focused? But i am guessing that is because the path and rectangle are not within the control template but when I add them into the control template this will not work either.

Comment: @Ziggy31 .. Rebuild your solution after changing code and try again. I copied your code and paste it in my WPF Application. I Changed all of `Storyboard.TargetName` to `Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=rectangle}"` and I Removed `x:Key="TextBoxStyle1"` from the style and when run it works fine. When i focused on textbox the rectangle was appeared.

Comment: @user2946329 - I get this error hmm! I'm doing everything you have said. '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[0].(2)'.

Comment: @user2946329 done :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by doing two things:

1. Remove `x:Key="TextBoxStyle1"` from your style
2. Instead of using `Storyboard.TargetName`, use `Storyboard.Target` like this:

   ```
   Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=rectangle}"
   ```